# Making JS EventListener run constantly

Tags: javascript, html, css

A couple of days ago someone here offered me a solution for a script that changes the color of a div when scrolling.

This is the code I used:

```
    const x = document.getElementById("menuID");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 105 && window.pageYOffset < 775){
        x.classList.add("color1");
    } else {
        x.classList.add("color2");
    }
});
```

It works, nevertheless I want it to keep functioning after the page loaded, so its able to change to ''color.2''. Is this possible?

Comment: One way would be to use the setTimeout() method in this way you can determine at what interval you want the function firing.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: My guess is that this is already the case. However, your div won't change back to its orginal color as the classess are added but not changed/removed.

Comment: As Frank points out, the code you've included says "Add this class, otherwise, add this other class". At no point does it *remove* or *toggle* any classes. Once you add `color2`, it never gets removed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I did in fact tried to use x.classList.remove("color1") in the else statement after reading you guys but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more event listener on you document and run the same callback from there also :

```
const x = document.getElementById("menuID");
function callback(){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 105 && window.pageYOffset < 775){
        x.classList.add("color1");
    } else {
        x.classList.add("color2");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",callback);
window.addEventListener("load",callback);
```