# Keep EventListener running untill the box is checked

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

**The Context**

I have a form where text fields must pass validation before the checkbox to accept terms and conditions is shown.

**The Problem**

I want the code to hide the element, even after validation has passed temporarily, for example, if a user changes the text in an input field to subsequently fail validation.

**Currently**

I have been successful so far in getting the checkbox to be hidden until validation has passed with:

```js
form.addEventListener("input", function(){
    eval();
    if (evalResult === true) {
        showBox();
    } else {
        hideBox();
    }
});
```

where `showBox` and `hideBox` use `object.style.visibility` to hide the respective DOM element.

The `eval()` function does the validation and returns a boolean to the `evalResult` variable.

**However**

If a user changes the text in an input field, after `showBox` has been called, the check box remains visible.
The issue with this, is that invalidated data may be sent to the server.

Some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55729174) shows that a loop may be the answer, but I can't have the loop running out.

Would this be a case for [using](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) a `debounce()`? I think that might unfortunately be a bit beyond my knowledge at the moment.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit

If there is a way to keep the handler running until the checkbox is checked?

Edit 2
As requested here is the `eval()` function

```js
function eval () {
   
    let isFirstNameValid = checkFirstName(),
    isLastNameValid = checkLastName(),
    isEmailValid = checkEmail(),
    isTelephoneValid = checkTelephone();

    let isFormValid = 
    isFirstNameValid &&
    isLastNameValid &&
    isEmailValid &&
    isTelephoneValid;

    if (isFormValid) {
        evalResult = true;
    }
};
```

Edit 3

I have changed the name of the `eval()` function to `evaluate()` to not interfere with the existing `eval()` function..

Edit 4
**The Working Code**

```js
function showBox() {
    document.getElementById("terms").style.visibility = "visible";
    console.log("a wild box appeared!");
};

function hideBox() {
    document.getElementById("terms").style.visibility = "hidden";
    console.log("the box fled!");
};

let valid = ""

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("input", function(){
    let valid = false;
    if (checkFirstName(),
    checkLastName(),
    checkEmail(),
    checkTelephone() === true) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    };
    console.log(valid);
    if (valid === true) {
        showBox();
    } else {
        hideBox();
    };
});
```

Comment: There was an answer but it’s been deleted?

Comment: If a user changes text in an input field, and it becomes invalid, won't that then make `evalResult` equal to `false` when `eval()` is called again, thus calling `hideBox()` and hiding your checkbox

Comment: I completely agree with you@NickParsons, I think @Yenmangu you should share your ```eval()``` function as well here.

Comment: Do you remove the event listener in the showbox() function?

Comment: @Nikkkshit yeah I will do in a bit. The eval() functions are the culmination of different evaluation methods performed on the input. I tried to modularise myself code to reduce needlessly long functions

Comment: You should check weather you evalResult is getting set to false or not, when the validation gets failed.

Comment: I have it working!! Should I answer my own question?

Comment: @Yenmangu yes you should answer your own question. You can move Edit 4 into an answer below and add some explanation around what you did incorrectly and what you've changed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to `setTimeout`!
Simply call it with a `callback` and a `time` (in milliseconds) and it will call your `callback` once the `time` has passed.

Also I highly suggest not using `eval` in 99.9% of cases.

```js
const formEl = document.querySelector("form");
const firstNameEl = formEl.querySelector("input[name='firstName']");
const lastNameEl = formEl.querySelector("input[name='lastName']");
const acceptTermsLabelEl = formEl.querySelector("label");

const validate = () => {
    if (!firstNameEl.value || !firstNameEl.value.length)
    return false;
    if (!lastNameEl.value || !lastNameEl.value.length)
    return false;
  
  return true;
}

const showBox = () => {
    acceptTermsLabelEl.style.display = "initial";
}

const hideBox = () => {
    acceptTermsLabelEl.style.display = "none";
}

let showBoxTimeout = null;

formEl.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const isValid = validate();
  
  if (isValid) {
    if (!showBoxTimeout)
        // store our setTimeout in a variable to avoid duplications of the setTimeout
        showBoxTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        validate() ? showBox() : hideBox()
        if (validate())
            showBox();
        else
            hideBox();
          
        showBoxTimeout = null;
        
      }, 3000);
  } else {
    hideBox();
  }
```

Here's a JSFiddle to mess around with! https://jsfiddle.net/5wtf0gyv/

Comment: My function `eval()` is only called that out of my choosing

Comment: @Yenmangu oooh gotcha

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: It was helpful, but I went with an event listener on input, as I have edited my question above to show. I upvoted your answer because it was fascinating reading about it and I am sure I will be using it in the future for an upcoming project.